# Testing failures with Adaptive Payments

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

Is there any way how to test various failures in sandbox when using Adaptive Payments API?

[Here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/lifecycle/ug_sandbox/#errors) it says that the negative testing is for Classic PayPal APIs only :(

Thanks.